# Update display accordingly to yield function each frame

Tags: python, animation, pygame, grid

I'm trying to implement a pathfinding algorithm visualizer using a yield function on my algorithm that yields the list of visited nodes each time it visits one at the end of my function:

```
# Breadth First Search Algorithm
def bfs(graph, start, goal):
    explored = []

    # Queue for traversing the
    # graph in the BFS
    queue = [[start]]

    # If the desired node is
    # reached
    if start == goal:
        return

    # Loop to traverse the graph
    # with the help of the queue

    while queue:
        path = queue.pop(0)
        node = path[-1]
        y, x = node
        # Codition to check if the
        # current node is not visited

        if node not in explored and nodes_rows[x][y].color is not BLACK:

            neighbours = graph[node]

            # Loop to iterate over the
            # neighbours of the node
            for neighbour in neighbours:
                new_path = list(path)
                new_path.append(neighbour)
                queue.append(new_path)

                # Condition to check if the
                # neighbour node is the goal
                if neighbour == goal:
                    new_path.remove(start)
                    new_path.remove(goal)
                    return new_path

            explored.append(node)
            yield explored
    return None
```

`nodes_rows[x][y].color is not BLACK` - avoid walls that have the color black

and I have a main loop that visualizes the algorithm when enter button is pressed:

```
if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
    algorithm = bfs(neihgbours, (start[0]), (end[0]))
    ticks = None        

    try:
        while True:
            if not ticks or pygame.time.get_ticks() - ticks >= 500:
                ticks = pygame.time.get_ticks()
                nodes = next(algorithm)
                nodes_rows[nodes[-1][1]][nodes[-1][0]].color = LIGHT_BLUE
                pygame.display.update()
    except StopIteration:
        pass
```

`nodes_rows[nodes[-1][1]][nodes[-1][0]].color = LIGHT_BLUE` This confusing part is basically taking the row of the last element in the list `nodes[-1][1]` and then the column of the last element in the list `nodes[-1][0]` and then in the `nodes_rows` matrix it changes the node color accordingly to that, the list is made out of (row, column) tuples for better clarification. For even better representation if I print `nodes = next(algorithm)` the output will look like this:

```py
[(7, 6)]
[(7, 6), (8, 6)]
[(7, 6), (8, 6), (6, 6)]
[(7, 6), (8, 6), (6, 6), (7, 5)]
[(7, 6), (8, 6), (6, 6), (7, 5), (7, 7)]
[(7, 6), (8, 6), (6, 6), (7, 5), (7, 7), (9, 6)]
...
```

I'm trying to get the algorithm to color nodes on a grid a node per half a second and it does work on the yield function if I print it, it actually does add a node each 0.5 to the visited nodes list but for some reason when I try to update the screen and color them it just waits the total amount of ticks and colors all at once instead of a more animation kind of look to it. How can I update the display so that it will color node by node instead of every single visited node at the end of the algorithm function using yield?

For better understanding here is what the grid looks like after finishing coloring all the nodes at once:

[image]

Video to represent the algorithm in the process:

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/772816508015083552/832303260911272046/PowerPoint_-_1_2021-04-15_20-13-35_Trim.mp4

Comment: Do not add fake tags like "[pygame]" to the title. Use the tag section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have a `while` loop inside your event loop or you main game loop. Use a flag instead to signal whether or not to update the algorithm:

```py
algorithm = None
update_timer = 0
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while running:
    dt = clock.tick()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # ... Other event handling
        if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
            algorithm = bfs(neihgbours, (start[0]), (end[0]))
            update_timer = 500 # To make sure we update first time

    update_timer += dt
    if algorithm and update_timer > 500:
        update_timer -= 500
        try:
            nodes = next(algorithm)
        except StopIteration:
            algorithm = None
        else:
            nodes_rows[nodes[-1][1]][nodes[-1][0]].color = LIGHT_BLUE
     
     # The actual rendering should happen here.
```

Comment: @Megalng My previous comment got deleted for language but man I love you so freaking much I was trying to do it for like 2 days and no success until you helped me with that I'm so happy right now that it finally works without you I would probably give up on it at some point after trying so much